# Using react-router loaders, how can I redirect to a log-in route if a fetch done in the loader results in a 401?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router-dom

In my React application, I use react-router loaders to do API calls against the back end.
Sample route:

```
{
    element: <UserProfile/>,
    loader: () => fetch("/api/userprofile")
}
```

If the user is not logged in, the response from `/api/userprofile` will be 401 unauthorized.

What is the best way to accomplish the following:  *"When a `fetch` in a loader indicates that a user is not logged in, I want to navigate to another router element that displays the log-in UI"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`redirect`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect), with a `try-catch`, as they say, *"Because you can return or throw responses in loaders and actions, you can use redirect to redirect to another route"*. For example, like so:

```js
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";
```

```js
const loader = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("/api/userprofile");
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw Error("User Invalid");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return redirect("/login");
  }
};
```

```js
<Route path="/user" loader={loader} element={<UserProfile />} />
```

I moved `loader` outside as a separate function just for readability.